# system freezes when watching videos online such as youtube

Tags: video, freeze

when i start to watch videos online my laptop freezes and becomes unresponsive.The audio of the video can be heard as a loop. The only solution is to turn of the system using the power button. when system boots up after this issue there is a message "recovering journal"
and it shows some nodes and their id's.is there any solution for this?????